# Long overlay in Singapore (Changi Airport)- How to get a visa to travel outside?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, singapore

I am an Indian passport holder travelling via Changi(Singapore) to AKL(Auckland Airport). Layover is for 13 hours. I want to travel outside the airport and see the city.

What kind of visa do I need and how to obtain this?

Answer (score 7):

> As an Indian national and holding a valid New Zealand Visa , you are
> eligible to transit in Singapore airport for one transit
> (96 Hours)
> provided you have valid ticket and visa for onward journey to one of
> the following countries:

Answer is from official immigration and checkpoint authority Singapore
Source : https://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=96

[image]

**Visa Free Transit Facility (VFTF)**

General Conditions:

- Transit travellers who satisfy the criteria for VFTF will have to
  meet the prevailing entry requirements before they are allowed entry
  into Singapore. Assessment for entry is determined by the Immigration
  & Checkpoints Authority (ICA) officers at the point of entry.
- Extension of stay for transit travellers under the VFTF is strictly
  not allowed

You don't need a Singapore visa for this itinerary, simply you can avail transit visa at Singapore immigration in Changi Airport